# What argument do I use when calling draw() function?

Tags: swift, line, draw

I want to draw a line programmatically in swift. I have working code for it (I think), but calling the function requires a `CGRect` argument. And I'm unsure what code to write there.

The draw() class and function looks like this:

```
class LineView : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        var aPath = UIBezierPath()

        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:2, y:2))

        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:6, y:6))

        aPath.close()
    }
}
```

Now calling it from the main `ViewDidLoad` it would look like this:

```
var line = LineView()
line.draw(MISSING ARGUMENT)
```

But I have no idea what argument I'm supposed to pass. Nothing of the `CGRect` is used in the function, so I'm not even sure of its purpose.

***UPDATE***
In main I create the object like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gameBoard: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var line = LineView()

        gameBoard.addSubview(line)

    }
}
```

And my draw class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class LineView : UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) { 
    super.init(frame: frame) //super = DO REGULAR INIT STUFF FOR UIView

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        var aPath = UIBezierPath()

        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:2, y:2))

        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:6, y:6))

        aPath.close()

        UIColor.red.set()
        aPath.stroke()
        aPath.fill()

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Got it working with:

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `draw(rect:` yourself. **Never** do.

It's implicitly called once by the framework after the view was initialized.

If you want to redraw the view call `setNeedsDisplay()` on the view.

Comment: I tried just `var line = LineView()     
        gameBoard.addSubview(line)` but nothing showed. Should I have a constructor perhaps?

Comment: Usually you have to initialize a view calling `init(frame` and passing at least width and height or to apply appropriate auto layout constraints.

Comment: I added a constructor and just initiated the object, see my update. But still nothing shows...

Comment: The added initializers are pointless as they only call `super`. You have to **call** `init(frame` and specify a rect for example `let line = LineView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))`

Comment: Ah, got it right with the `init` now. Thanks for your help @vadian!! :)